# Creating an "average grade list" for ranked IDs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, csv, average

**Problem description**

I'm trying to get a comma-separated list of average grades for each recommendation, which consists of another comma-separated list of recommended content IDs. A recommendation is an object which consists of content that will receive the recommendation (`ContentID`) and a list of other contents that will be recommended (`RecommendedContentIDs`).

**Table structure, sample data and other limitations**

<strike>I have a two table database structure. The first table contains a recommended content IDs saved as a comma-separated ranked list. The second table contains grades for each of the recommended content IDs. The ranked lists have up to 10 comma-separated values and grades range from 0 to 5.</strike>

To better illustrate the problem, here are the table structures and some sample data:

```
Table Recommendations

|ID    |ContentID    |RecommendedContentIDs |Type |
+------+-------------+----------------------+-----+
|1     |2051         |9706,14801,13354,...  |a    |
+------+-------------+----------------------+-----+
|67    |2051         |8103,16366,8795,...   |b    |
+------+-------------+----------------------+-----+
|133   |2051         |8795,8070,15341,...   |c    |
+------+-------------+----------------------+-----+
|22    |1234         |4782,283,33,...       |a    |
+------+-------------+----------------------+-----+
...

Table Grades

|ID    |RecommendationID |RecommendedDocumentID |Grade |EvaluatorHash|
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|1     |1                |9706                  |4     |123456789    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|2     |1                |14801                 |5     |123456789    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|3     |1                |13354                 |3     |987654321    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|3     |1                |9706                  |3     |987654321    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|4     |67               |8103                  |5     |123456789    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|1     |67               |16366                 |4     |987654321    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|1     |133              |8795                  |2     |123456789    |
+------+-----------------+----------------------+------+-------------+
...
```

**I've transformed the RecommendedContentIDs column in table Recommendations into a separate table that looks like this:**

```
Table RecommendedContent

|ID    |RecommendationID |RecommendedContentID |Rank |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|1     |1                |9706                 |1    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|2     |1                |14801                |2    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|3     |1                |13354                |3    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|4     |1                |12787                |4    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
...

+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|11    |2                |19042                |1    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|12    |2                |13376                |2    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|13    |2                |9853                 |3    |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
```

**Expected result**

I would now like to make a query that would return a result set that contains two comma-separated lists which are correspondent, so that I'll be able to display the average grade for each recommended content ID. It should look something like this:

```
|ContentID    |RecommendedContentIDs    |RecommendedContentAverageGrades   |Type  |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
|2051         |9706,14801,13354,...     |3.5,5.0,3.0,...                   |a     |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
|2051         |8103,16366,8795,...      |5.0,4.0,0.0,...                   |b     |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
|2051         |8795,8070,15341,...      |2.0,0.0,0.0,...                   |c     |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
...
```

As you can see, the `RecommendedContentAverageGrades` column contains the **average** grades for each corresponding ContentID in the column `RecommendedContentIDs` (Content with ID 9706 was graded twice, once with 4 and once with 3 therefore the average is 3.5). If the content hasn't been graded, the average grade should be 0. What is really important here is that the two comma-separated lists are **correspondent**, because the list in `RecommendedContentIDs` is a **ranked** list.

I would normally implement something like this in C#, but I was wondering whether it can be done with SQL. I was thinking of using `GROUP_CONCAT` but I wasn't able to get a proper result set. I would be very grateful if someone would provide a working SQL query for MySQL and/or T-SQL, but just suggestions will be fine too.

**Edits**

**#1** - Laurence mentioned using separate tables instead of comma-separated lists. I'm using them due to an old design, which I cannot change. However, I am open to answers which assume that data in comma-separated lists is stored in separate tables.

**#2** - Changed structure like Laurence suggested (using separated tables - see updated structure).

Comment: Is there any special reason you can't use separate tables instead of comma separated lists? You're only going to cause yourself pain doing it this way.

Comment: Those were my thoughts too, but unfortunately it's an old design (not mine) which I'm currently not able to change. If you have a solution that works with separate tables, please share it as an answer. I'll edit the question to encourage answers based on assumptions that data in comma-separated lists is in separate tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with Akrigg's fix and sql fiddle, also with how to order by values in the recommendation table
Also updated using order by in the group_concat clause as per brozo's fix:

```
Table RecommendedContent

+-----------------+----------------------+
|RecommendationID | RecommendedContentID |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1               | 9706                 |
| 1               | 14801                |
| 1               | 13354                |
| 67              | 8103                 |
| ...             | ...                  |
+-----------------+----------------------+

Select
  a.RecommendationID,
  a.ContentID,
  Group_Concat(a.RecommendedContentId Order By a.Rank),
  Group_Concat(Trim(Trailing '.' From Trim(Trailing '0' From a.AverageGrade)) Order By a.Rank),
  a.Type
From (
  Select
    r.RecommendationID,
    r.ContentID,
    r.Type,
    rc.RecommendedContentID,
    rc.Rank,
    Coalesce(Avg(g.Grade), 0) As AverageGrade
  From
    Recommendations r
      Left Outer Join
    RecommendedContent rc
      On r.RecommendationID = rc.RecommendationID
      Left Outer Join
    Grades g
      On rc.RecommendedContentID = g.RecommendedDocumentID And
         rc.RecommendationID = g.RecommendationID
  Group By
    r.RecommendationID,
    r.ContentID,
    r.Type,
    rc.RecommendedContentID,
    rc.Rank
  ) as a
Group By
  a.RecommendationID,
  a.ContentID,
  a.Type
Order By
  a.ContentID, -- Or other way round if that's what you prefer
  a.RecommendationID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8b8/8

Answer (score 3):

This just follows up the answer given by @Laurence:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d236/6

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't realise the way group_concat dealt with nulls. You can simplify the average with coalesce: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d236/8

Comment: I tried Laurence's solution and yours, and this comes very close to what I need, the only downside now is that the previously ranked order of RecommendedContentIDs is messed up. Is there a way to keep the original order?

Comment: @brozo SQL has no real concept of the order of rows in a table. Is there some combination of columns in Recommendations that gives the order you need?

Comment: @Laurence, the order is obtained from a previous process. The previous developer decided it would be best to save the ordered list as a comma-separated string of IDs. I've now transformed this to reflect your advice on using separate tables. I could however run a query which takes ContentID as an input and returns these IDs ranked in the form of an SQL result set. Do you have any suggestions on how that might be added to your solution?

Comment: @brozo If the sequence of values is important in the comma separate list then the new table also needs a sequence number.

Comment: @Laurence, I've added a Rank column to the RecommendedContent table, which provides a sequence number. How could I change the given query to get the expected result?

Comment: @Laurence, I managed to answer this question myself :) GROUP_CONCAT supports its own ORDER BY clause. Here is my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed99f/16/0 . Since you've provided the majority of this query, I've decided to give you the accepted answer. Maybe just edit it with my modifications, so that others will have a complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a custom aggreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx) in sql server to do the comma separated string concatenation and then use it like this:

```
SELECT ContentID, RecommendedContentIDs, CustomToCsv(AvgGrade), Type FROM
(
    SELECT ContentID, RecommendedContentIDs, AVG(Grade) AvgGrade, Type 
    FROM Recommendations r INNER JOIN  Grades g ON r.ID = g.RecommendationID
    GROUP BY ContentID, RecommendedContentIDs, RecommendedDocumentID, Type
) as t
GROUP BY ContentID, RecommendedContentIDs, Type
```

Comment: I tried this but instead of using a custom aggregate in MySQL, I used GROUP_CONCAT. The result is in the right format, but I don't get the zeros, for the RecommendedContentIDs that weren't graded. Also, the order in which it sorts the average grades is not correspondent to the RecommendedContentIDs list. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: I would try to use LEFT JOIN insted of INNER JOIN and replace AVG(Grade) with AVG(ISNULL(Grade,0) to include "ungraded" ones

Comment: is there any logic behind RecommendedContentIDs order? You have to ensure the same order in your aggregation result before applying GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Yes, RecommendedContentIDs is already ordered. How would I ensure the same order in the aggregation result before GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: the order of the id's seems to reflect grade tables row order. in that case it could be enough to exchange the tables on your join -> "Grades g RIGHT JOIN Recommendations r ON r.ID = g.RecommendationID" ->

Answer (score 1):

this is done in oracle

```
WITH count_number AS
  (SELECT 
    ContentID,
    ','
    ||RecommendedContentIDs
    ||',' new_ContentIDs,
    RecommendedContentIDs,
    type ,
    LENGTH(RECOMMENDEDCONTENTIDS )-LENGTH(REPLACE(RECOMMENDEDCONTENTIDS ,','))+1 COUNT_ID
  FROM Recommendations
  ) ,
  RecommendedContentIDs_postion AS
  (SELECT A1.*,
    B1.CONTENTIDS_OCCURANCE_POSITION ,
    SUBSTR(new_ContentIDs,instr(new_ContentIDs,',',1,ContentIDs_OCCURANCE_POSITION)+1 , INSTR(new_ContentIDs,',',1,ContentIDs_OCCURANCE_POSITION+1)-instr(new_ContentIDs,',',1,ContentIDs_OCCURANCE_POSITION)-1) ContentIDs
  FROM count_number a1,
    (SELECT I ContentIDs_OCCURANCE_POSITION
    FROM DUAL model dimension BY (1 i) measures (0 X) (X[FOR I
    FROM 2 TO 1000 increment 1] = 0)
    ) b1
  WHERE b1.ContentIDs_OCCURANCE_POSITION<=a1.count_id
  )
SELECT 
  CONTENTID,
  WM_CONCAT(CONTENTIDS) RECOMMENDEDCONTENTIDS ,
  WM_CONCAT(GRADE) avg_grade_contentid ,
  type
FROM RECOMMENDEDCONTENTIDS_POSTION RCI,
  (SELECT RECOMMENDEDDOCUMENTID,
    AVG(GRADE) GRADE
  FROM Grades
  GROUP BY RECOMMENDEDDOCUMENTID
  ) GRD
WHERE TRIM(RCI.CONTENTIDS)=TRIM(GRD.RECOMMENDEDDOCUMENTID)
GROUP BY 
  ContentID,
  type;
```